# How do I protect my AJAX services?

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, jquery

Right now I'm working on a service that handles reviews/recommendations of local restaurants overlayed on Google Maps. Basically Yelp, but restricted to a certain niche. Anyhow, since I don't want to have to load every location and review at once, I'm finally getting into using jQuery and AJAX calls.

The question I have is: How do I prevent other people from 'scraping' data from my ajax scripts on the server?

The main map/location info functionality needs to be public, in that users should not have to log in to use the application, so it may simply boil down to making it *difficult* to scrape. I'm hoping that one of you AJAX veteran out there can point me in the direction of a better idea, or some 'best practices' docs that I haven't been able to find yet.

So far all I've been able to come up with is:

- The user-facing scripts open a short-lived session on the server and the AJAX calls will not run without an active session.
- Send some sort of access key along with the application code and require that in all of the AJAX calls. But not sure how to best implement this in a way that's not trivially easy to get around.

Comment: Keep in mind JS is essentially open source. The closest you can get is obfuscation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't completely protect your AJAX web services.  Even if you mangle your data and obfuscate your source code, it is trivial to just fire up a packet sniffer or debugging proxy, figure it out, and scrape from it.

What I would do is exactly what you propose... only users with an active session on the site can make calls.  Then from there, throttle requests.

Even a busy normal user won't make more than a handful of requests per minute.  You can analyze your logs to figure out what a good number would be.  Even if you limited your service to 20 calls per minute, that kind of limitation makes it fairly useless for folks that want to duplicate all of your content.

Don't limit just on session data either... keep an eye on IP addresses.  It's entirely possible to fire off a request and get a new session at any time.  Periodically check your logs to see if anything is getting through, and adjust your strategy accordingly.

Finally, regularly search for your content.  Google is a great tool for finding copyright infringers.  If you use specific data, such as GPS coordinates, you can actually watermark the coordinates with a specific value in the noise area of the coordinate.

Comment: I had been thinking of adding a few 'Red Herring' locations, but watermarking the coords is new to me. How far down into the decimal places does this 'noise' area exist?

Comment: @Sammitch, That depends on your accuracy needs and location on the globe.  (For example, higher latitudes have smaller distances between longitude degrees.)  Suppose I'm at Congress and Michigan Ave in Chicago, and I want to walk across Michigan (6 lanes and a median).  I would go from -87.62440 to -87.62413 longitude.  If you use double precision floats for coordinates, you can easily give yourself a few digits for watermarking, without budging the accuracy of the coordinate.  Remember that most GPS units aren't accurate to more than 15 ft. anyway!  (Cellular assisted GPS is more accurate.)

Comment: @Sammitch anything over 5 decimal places is less than 1 metre at the equator see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

Answer (score 1):

From what I hear, you want to protect the JavaScript side of the service. This is not possible as JavaScript is essentially fully open source (albeit not public domain)

Google offers a [tool called Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/) which can compact the script by removing white space and tabs. It can also obfuscate a document for you by replacing variable names and function names with random characters. It is customizable so you can tell it what you want. From what I can tell, Google uses it for their own website (evident by viewing the source of their pages)

Comment: JavaScript obfuscation isn't of much use, especially since what he really needs to protect is the data being accessed.  Google doesn't obfuscate their code as much as they minify their code, which has a similar effect, but with the goal of making code smaller for downloading.

Comment: @Brad minify is essentially the best obfuscation you can get with no knowledge of obfuscation in JavaScript. It will deter any would-be-hackers (ones trying to enter the hacking world)